# No option to use image as texture

Tags: texturing

I'm using Blender 2.79 on windows through the steam app.  When I set a texture, I can only use a solid colour as there are no other options available.  There is no small circle visible on the right side of the colour pane that I've just watched many tutorials click and bring up a new menu where I would select what type of texture you want.  I'm in Blender Render mode.  I've restarted Blender multiple times.[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxdhM.png

Comment: Thanks.  It may surprise you to learn I am new to Blender :D

Answer (score 2):

In 'Blender Render' adding the texture in the Texture tab (The checkers next to the material tab) will automatically add it to the material.

[image]

The uploaders of the tutorials are probably using the cycles renderer for the tutorial which is why they had to add the texture in the material tab.